Nexus yum proxy to amazon2023 - No more mirrors to try
Trying to configure amazon al2023 yum repo proxy to nexus yum repository and added in nexus.repo file.
$yum list is working but $yum install <package> is throwing an error.
Error -
Downloading Packages:
[MIRROR] vim-data-9.0.2153-1.amzn2023.noarch.rpm: Status code: 404 for https://nexus.server.com:8443/blobstore/6361a97ec2421819a5048c8aed1affbfa37c0e2e93da/vim-data-9.0.2153-1.amzn2023.noarch.rpm (IP: 10.x.x.x)  
[MIRROR] vim-data-9.0.2153-1.amzn2023.noarch.rpm: Status code: 404 for https://nexus.server.com:8443/blobstore/6361a97ed1affbfd610741a37c0e2b9essouvgv93da/vim-data-9.0.2153-1.amzn2023.noarch.rpm (IP: 10.x.x.x)  
[MIRROR] vim-data-9.0.2153-1.amzn2023.noarch.rpm: Status code: 404 for https://nexus.server.com:8443/blobstore/6361a97d1affbfd610xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/vim-data-9.0.2153-1.amzn2023.noarch.rpm (IP: 10.x.x.x)  
[MIRROR] vim-data-9.0.2153-1.amzn2023.noarch.rpm: Status code: 404 for https://nexus.server.com:8443/blobstore/6361a97ecfbfxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/vim-data-9.0.2153-1.amzn2023.noarch.rpm (IP: 10.x.x.x)  
[FAILED] vim-data-9.0.2153-1.amzn2023.noarch.rpm: No more mirrors to try - All mirrors were already tried without success                                                                                                                         

The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'yum clean packages'.
Error: Error downloading packages:
  vim-data-2:9.0.2153-1.amzn2023.noarch: Cannot download, all mirrors were already tried without success

help will be appriciated.
